# TENGO PROBLEMAS PARA MOSTRAR SWEET ALERT ANTES DE CERRAR SESION CON PHP

Tags: php, mysql, sweetalert2

Alguien puede ayudarme por favor? quiero hacer que la sesiòn se cierre cuando confirme el SweetAlert y no se muestra la alerta
Estoy intentando hacer que se cierre sesion cuando se confirme el sweetalert, pero cuando incluyo las lineas de cerrar sesion ya no se muestra la alerta y se cierra la sesion directamente

```
<?php 
    $boton1="";
    $boton2="";
    $boton3="";
    $btnconsulta="";
    if(isset($_POST['boton2']))$boton2=$_POST['boton2'];
      if($boton2)
    {
    ?>
    <script type="text/javascript">
      Swal
        .fire({
            title: "¿DESEA CONFIRMAR SU VOTO?",
            text: "¿Votar?",
            icon: 'warning',
            showCancelButton: true,
            confirmButtonText: "Sí, eliminar",
            cancelButtonText: "Cancelar",
        })
        .then(resultado => {
            if (resultado.value) {
                <?php
                require_once 'conexion.php';  
                     $DNI2=$_SESSION['dni'];
                     $GRADO2=$_SESSION['grado'];
                     $SECCION2=$_SESSION['seccion'];
                     $AP2=$_SESSION['apynombres'];
                     $sql = "INSERT IGNORE INTO votos (Eleccion,dni,grado,seccion,apynombres) VALUES(2,$DNI2,'$GRADO2','$SECCION2','$AP2')";
                     if (mysqli_query($conexion, $sql)) {
                     } else {
                            echo "Error: " . $sql . "<br>" . mysqli_error($conexion);
                     }
                     $sql = "UPDATE estudiantes SET condicion='Voto' WHERE DNI= $DNI2";
                      if ($conn->query($sql) === TRUE) {
                      session_destroy();
                      header('Location: index.php');
                      exit;   
                ?>  
            } else {
                // Dijeron que no
                console.log("No se emitio el voto");
            }
        });
    </script>
    <?php 
            } else {
              echo "Error al actualizar: " . $conn->error;
            }
            $conn->close();
         mysqli_close($conexion);
    ?>
    <?php 
         }
    ?>
```

Alguien puede ayudarme por favor? quiero hacer que la sesiòn se cierre cuando confirme el SweetAlert y no se muestra la alerta
Estoy intentando hacer que se cierre sesion cuando se confirme el sweetalert, pero cuando incluyo las lineas de cerrar sesion ya no se muestra la alerta y se cierra la sesion directamente

Comment: El principal problema aquí es querer meter código PHP en el contexto del cliente. Considera usar Ajax o la nueva API Fetch de Javascript. Así, metes todo el código de servidor en su contexto y desde el cliente recibes las respuestas del servidor y actúas en consecuencia.

Comment: @A.Cedano Gracias por responder, soy principìante en esto, por si acaso tendras algun codigo de ejemplo para guiarme por favor¿?

Comment: Aquí mismo hay varias preguntas sobre Ajax y sobre Fetch y en la web hay tutoriales. Es importante que leas primero cómo funciona y luego irás sobre ruedas. El concepto básico es que, en PHP tendrás un archivo que recibirá los datos del cliente, los procesará y enviará una respuesta. En el cliente recibirás esa respuesta y actuarás en consecuencia, con la ventaja de que no tendrás que recargar la página cada vez que necesites enviar algo o recibir algo. Al principio podría parecer complicado, pero entendiendo los conceptos básicos verás que no lo es. Y cualquier problema te ayudaremos.

Comment: @A.Cedano gracias, mientras voy estudiando lo que me sugieres, habria otra forma de implementar una alerta simple sin sweetaler? lo necesito urgente ayudame por favor.

Comment: ¿A qué te refieres con *alerta simple* ? ¿Te refieres a la función `alert()` de Javascript?

Comment: @A.Cedano probe con esa funciòn e igual no se muestra, se va directo al cierre de sesion, en cambio cuando quito el codigo de cierre de sesion ahi si se muestra

Comment: Ya, el problema principal es lo que te vengo diciendo: estás queriendo ejecutar código del servidor en el cliente. Dedícale unos 30 minutos a Ajax o a Fetch y tendrás tu programa mejor encaminado. No podrás verificar cosas en el servidor desde el cliente fácilmente si no usas esas herramientas.